# How to get selected values of all dynamically created multiple dropdowns using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created dynamically row with drop-down list, i want to get all selected values from dropdowns of rows with JQuery. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posed any code snippet, I'm just gonna wing it, assuming it's a standard `<select>`-box.

```js
// Loop all parents and grab the value which is set by the browser whenever update occurs.
var values = [...document.querySelectorAll('select')].map(x =>x.value)
```